# value error while implementing the stochastic regression using sklearn library in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

There is need to update training set automatically when new observations are filled.

I have used Stochastic Gradient Descent Algorithm using sklearn library in Python. I converted dataframe to array but still I am having problem in conversion. I do this following:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

#Collecting Numeric data
data = pd.read_csv('/home/system/Documents/Heena/Regression/Data.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['years_of_exp', 'company',   'location', 'education','score'])

xSGD = df[['years_of_exp', 'company', 'location', 'education']]
ySGD = df['score']

#Conversion of dataframe to numpy array
X = np.asarray(xSGD)
Y = np.asarray(ySGD)
clf = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", penalty="l2", max_iter=5)
clf.fit(xSGD,ySGD)
```

Error:
I expect the output of this must fit the model. But the actual output is

```
ValueError.

 File "/home/system/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 96, in unique_labels
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys))
ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([1.  , 2.  , 3.  , 3.8 , 4.  , 4.25, 5.  ]),)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace, I see two problems:

1. `ySGD` is a tuple, but it should be a numpy array (probably the first and only element of that tuple)
2. You are using `SGDClassifier`, but your labels are real numbers (and are called "score" in the dataframe). This suggests your task is actually a regression problem, so you should use `SGDRegressor` instead

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you so much @BlackBear :)